# OTA install of app (jailbreak) doesn't work

Tags: html, ios, jailbreak, ota

I have made an app in Xcode (without a developer certificate, so for jailbroken devices).

I tried to make an over the air (itms) install with it, but when I try to install it always say:

> Unable to Download MyApp …

I tried to install the ipa file with AppCake (installous alternative), and that works… Why?

(I have AppSync installed)

Does someone have a solution please?

**Upadate** : Yes, the right URL of the ipa is in the plist file…

**Update 2** : This is the console at the moment I tap install on my site… :

```
Apr 30 18:28:23 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer sandboxd[2216] <Notice>: MS:Notice: Installing: (null) [sandboxd] (793.00)
Apr 30 18:28:23 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer syncdefaultsd[2202] <Warning>: com.apple.mobilesafari has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
Apr 30 18:28:23 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer syncdefaultsd[2202] <Warning>: Can't get application info for com.apple.mobilesafari
Apr 30 18:28:23 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer syncdefaultsd[2202] <Warning>: com.apple.mobilesafari has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
Apr 30 18:28:23 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer syncdefaultsd[2202] <Warning>: Can't get application info for com.apple.mobilesafari
Apr 30 18:28:23 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer syncdefaultsd[2202] <Warning>: com.apple.mobilesafari has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
Apr 30 18:28:23 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer syncdefaultsd[2202] <Warning>: Can't get application info for com.apple.mobilesafari
Apr 30 18:28:23 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer syncdefaultsd[2202] <Warning>: com.apple.mobilesafari has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement
Apr 30 18:28:23 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer syncdefaultsd[2202] <Warning>: Can't get application info for com.apple.mobilesafari
Apr 30 18:28:24 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer installd[44] <Error>: 0x2ffec000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/3841534856026300275/-2859867327384530431" requested by itunesstored
Apr 30 18:28:24 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer installd[44] <Error>: 0x2ffec000 extract_package: Could not extract archive
Apr 30 18:28:24 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer installd[44] <Error>: 0x2ffec000 stage_package: Could not extract /var/mobile/Media/Downloads/3841534856026300275/-2859867327384530431 to /var/tmp/install_staging.reTUPC/foo_extracted
Apr 30 18:28:24 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer itunesstored[151] <Error>: 0x1ab4000 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
Apr 30 18:28:24 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer installd[44] <Error>: 0x2ffec000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Could not stage the package
Apr 30 18:28:24 iPhone-van-Evert-De-Spiegeleer installd[44] <Error>: 0x2ffec000 handle_install: API failed
```

Comment: I would recommend to look at console logs for more info.

Comment: @VictorRonin i added it to the question ^^

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question:
[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097174/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore-error-no-valid-com-apple-developer-ubiquity-kvstore-i)

And particularly answer regarding AppSync.