# Xcode-5 Validation error. Invalid code Signing Entitlements

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I am trying to upload the application on AppStore but due to invalid code signing entitlements I cant upload the application and after alot of search and solutions I am posting this issue here. For more details I have attached a screen shot herewith in which issue is precisely described. [image]

Comment: What you have defined as bundle identifier?

Comment: This is my bundle Identifier com.infrontandabove.slapic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097174/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore-error-no-valid-com-apple-developer-ubiquity-kvstore-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have the web browser to app handoff entitlement in your app, but it needs to be an explicit domain, not *.  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH2-SW10

Open your Capabilities tab for your project, in Xcode and look for this: com.apple.developer.associated-domains

If you don't want to use Handoff, you can likely disable that or removed it.

**Edit:** I've added two screenshots. One is the Capabilities tab of your target, make sure Associated Domains is turned off.  The second is the Entitlements file, find your MyProject.Entitlements file in the project and delete the key for associated-domains.

**Edit 2:** Added a screenshot of the developer account App ID.

[image: Associated Domains Capabilities]

[image: Entitlements File Associated Domains]

[image]

Comment: I could find com.apple.developer.associated-domains under capabilities tab in Xcode-5 can you please elaborate it more or give me the screen shot of that. Thanks

Comment: I added screenshots to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I have used all the steps that have been mentioned through these screenshots but still I am getting the same validation error. Thanks for your cooperation but I am getting the same validation problem.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your Entitlements file? Also, log on to your Apple Developer account and verify that the App ID has it disabled.  (See my new screenshot.) Also, do a clean and rebuild...

Comment: Thanks You make my day... The new screenshot of developer portal works :) Once again Thankyou so much...